# Integers not dividing powers of smaller integers

Tags: integers

What are the sufficient conditions on a positive integer $n$ such that it does not divide $m^r$ for any $m<n$ and $r\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: What sort of tools have you used in related problems?  Can any of those tools work here?  Have you considered things like lcm or gcd and the like?  Have you considered any special classes of numbers?

Comment: Suggestion: work out which integers from $1$ up to say $20$ have this property.  If you can find out which do, and which don't, **and why**, you should be a good way towards solving the problem.